# Running visual studio code in the current folder with batch file

Tags: visual-studio, cmd

I can follow below sequence of actions to run the Visual Studio Code in the current folder.

select the location bar in the current folder and run
(ALT + D):

`cmd /k code .`

I've tried to wrap the code . in the batch file (and place it in a folder where is declared in the PATH variable to run it as its own), it launches "Visual Studio Code" but doesn't close the command window until i close the visual studio code.

i know "start" command need to be there with exit command in the end but so far the combinations i've tried didn't really let me achieve that.

`cmd.exe /k code .
exit`

Any ideas?

Comment: The `/K` switch tells cmd.exe to remain. Use `cmd.exe /?` and see the `/C` switch.

Comment: Sure but how to call it from a batch file to make sure it closes when the command is executed with the cmd

Comment: I think I'm running into the same issue.  Whether I use, cmd /k, cmd /c, start, call, or even code.exe directly - none of those commands will allow the shell to exit until code.exe has exited.  This is very frustrating.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this works for me,
Do not omit the first empty quote

`Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe" <path_to_dir>\.`

Comment: Thank you, first empty quote was the missing piece.

Comment: The empty quote was just what I needed to start Code from batch without the command prompt in the background.

Comment: For me, I must run the script as administrator and it works as expected

Comment: Banged my head for half day...until i found this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (be sure to start `code` and `exit` at the bottom of the batch file):

```
start "" code
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

It works fine when I create cmd file with that script on the Windows 10 OS:

```sh
code c:\\path\\to\\Project | exit
```

Comment: dont forget add new line end of the file

Comment: this code is much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to start vscode from current folder from command line
type

> code %cd%

Answer (score 1):

## Starts *Visual Studio Code* in *current* folder

```
@start code .
```

## Starts *Visual Studio Code* in *specific* folder

```
@start code "<Specific Folder>"
```

## Starts *Visual Studio Code* with a *specific file*

```
@start code "<Specific File>"
```

Save file as *.bat*

Comment: @Krissh +1 for doing it with the _code_. Can you please elaborate what **B** does?

Comment: @PriyeshDiukar  /B will exit only the script (or subroutine) but not CMD.

Answer (score 0):

[Run as] VS code extention for "Right click a file to run as the parameter of command in terminal."

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=plylrnsdy.run-as

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in command prompt and powershell:
`call code`
It works for me.